# Showing RDLC report in Asp.Net with report viewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, rdlc

Am using VS 2010 and created a sample web application. Added a dataset and report and created an SP which just return one row. No variables included as of now. Just simple SP w/o any parameters. In the web app, added an aspx page and in that page added a report viewer control.
 My Aspx page goes as below:

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Code behind goes as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", LoadData().Tables[0]);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }

        private DataSet LoadData()
        {
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand("[spSampleReport]")
                                  {
                                      Connection = con,
                                      CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                                  };

                var adap = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                con.Open();
                adap.Fill(dataset, "DataSet1");
            }

            return dataset;
        }
```

In my web config, have added following in httphandlers section:

When Running, there is nothing shown on the page. Even the report viewer toolbars are not shown.

Comment: an error thrown when you debug?

Answer (score 2):

I am no ReportViewer expert but I think you need an .rdlc to tell the report viewer what to render.

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format(@"~\Reports\Definitions\{0}.rdlc", reportName));
```

Make sure the DataSet name in the .rdlc is the same as the DataSource specified when you create you **ReportDataSource**

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example to generate rdlc reports in asp.net with code example

http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/09/how-to-create-rdlc-reports-in-aspnet.html#.UjhvAsafh88